# Android Dependency configurations

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been reading the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) to learn more about how Gradle manage the dependencies in an Android project.

Finally I understand The Java Library Plugin decide how to build and run a project using the following configurations.

- api
- implementation
- compileOnly
- runtimeOnly

However I'm trying to check the differences of those configurations using android libraries as retrofit, glide or okHttp and I'm not able to find one.
For example, let's say I want to try OkHttp.

Using **API**

```
api "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.6.0"
```

Using **implementation**

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.6.0"
```

I don't see any difference in `Project -> External Libraries -> com.squareup.okhttp3` or using `./gradlew app:androidDependencies`

I'm not sure if this configurations are only useful in a multimodule project, where its easier check the differences (at least api vs implementation).

If I go deeper in the OkHttp `pom.xml` I don't know which configuration is used: `api`, `implementation`, `compileOnly`, `runtimeOnly`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.7</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <name>OkHttp</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
      <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.conscrypt</groupId>
      <artifactId>conscrypt-openjdk-uber</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-all</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>animal-sniffer-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>filter-sources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludePackageNames>okhttp3.internal:okhttp3.internal.*</excludePackageNames>
          <links>
            <link>http://square.github.io/okio/</link>
          </links>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Automatic-Module-Name>okhttp3</Automatic-Module-Name>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

## Questions

1. How can check the difference between configurations using a remote library instead of submodules.
2. How `pom.xml` knows about its configurations dependencies?
3. Maybe OkHttp is not the best example, is there any better to explain this questions?

Could someone give me a hand? I can provide more details if needed. Or I can pay for support haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gradle project has the dependency Okhttp.

Okhttp is a maven project.

Gradle and maven are both build tools and they essentially do the same thing, the `pom.xml` is the maven equivalent to the `build.gradle` file.

If you look at the `pom.xml` from OKhttp, you can see dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>animal-sniffer-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The `<scope>` is the maven equivalent to the gradle configuration (e.g. `implementation`, `api`,...).

Take a look at [this](http://andresalmiray.com/maven-scopes-vs-gradle-configurations/) in order to compare them:

```
maven - gradle
compile - compile
provided - compileOnly, testCompileOnly (only gradle)
system (maven only, local JAR)
runtime - runtime
test - testCompile, testRuntime
```

The official documentation of scopes can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope).

A remote library is a library that you just import in your project. It is uploaded to a repository like jcenter or maven central.

A submodule is a part of the project that is also located in the project. If the parent project is e.g. compiled, the submodule will be compiled too.

---

Feel free to comment if I forgot anything. I will try to edit my answer in that case.

Comment: Amazing answer, I've just read the link that you provided and it raise more questions to me. There isn't an equivalent to `api` and `implementation` in Maven hence both should be consider as the deprecated `compile`, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks you for such a useful answer, I have more questions but tell me if you prefer I create a new questions or if you feel comfortable continue here and updating my question.

Comment: It is generally encouraged to create new questions if you have them. It is even a close reason (`Needs more focus`) that there are multiple questions in one.

Comment: I think maven does always resolve transitive dependencies(so both would be `compile`), except they are declared `optional`.

Comment: I create a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696863/gradle-compileonly-and-runtimeonly

Comment: I would appreciate you awarding my answer with the bounty if it is what you looked for.

Comment: done. I have created another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699706